# Python array stores boolean value as an array

Tags: python

I have the following python code which compares two numbers and stores either true or false in the array.
However, in stead of storing it like this:

```
 [True, False, True....]
```

It stores it like this:

```
[array([ True]), array([ False]), array([ True])]
```

Here's the code:

```
def runSample(file_name):
    samples=open(file_name,'r').readlines()
    result=[]
    check = False
    for line in samples:
        data=json.loads(line);
        check=data[-1]==clf.predict([data[:-1]])
        result.append(check)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Try `result.append(check).item()`

Comment: Gives error. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: Well you have Nones... So add a `if check is not None`

Comment: Can you share a sample of `samples`

Comment: Why not perform all predictions at once?? Just filter None's and predict all valid data at once. Your current solution will be slow for a lot of data

Comment: `clf.predict()` returns an array() type. What happens when you compare a number to the array() type? I'm guessing the result of the comparison returns the bool in an array type.

Comment: @kamion, you are correct, the comparison returns a bool in an array type. Any workaround to this while maintaining the append function?

Comment: I'm just wildly guessing here, but can you just reference the array element directly? Maybe `result.append(check[0])`? I don't know how this array type works. :D You can wrap it in a try-except and just ignore any NoneType errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if check is not None:
    result.extend(check)
```

This will add `check` items to `result`

Comment: I accept this answer. Though it's a bit slower than append, but it does the job.